# React native dynamic links and referral handling with firebase

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I have a requirement to handle referrals with react-native-firebase/app and react-native-dynamic-links. Currently I dont have a good idea about the task. How should I start this task? Is there any resource that I should follow?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to official docs on using `@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links` https://rnfirebase.io/dynamic-links/usage